# Why i can't see the SQL part in Glimpse tool for webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, webforms, glimpse

I have installed Glimpse on visual studio 2012 but i can't see the SQL part in the Glimpse .

---

[image]

Comment: did you install Glimpse.WebForms  and Glimpse.Ado? only 2 packages ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the [Glimpse.Ado NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.Ado/) as well as it contains the necessary SQL related hooks.

If you are using Entity Framework then you can install one of the following NuGet packages

- [Glimpse.EF43 NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.EF43/)
- [Glimpse.EF5 NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.EF5/)
- [Glimpse.EF6 NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.EF6/)

The Glimpse.EFx NuGet packages will automatically install the [Glimpse.Ado NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.Ado/) as it depends on it.

Comment: It appears right now but the tab is disabled !!
I use `IfxConnection`,`IfxCommand` all the time in my queries ,is this the problem ?

Comment: If you are not using the [DbProviderFactories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactories.aspx) class, but are constructing instances of the `IfxConnection` and `IfxCommand` types manually, then there are no Glimpse SQL hooks attached, hence no SQL logging. We do have a guideline explaining how to [manually set up the ADO integration](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Manual-ADO-Integration) which should give you the necessary pointers on how to integrate those types with Glimpse

Comment: Thanks a lot ,Are there any tutorial videos for web forms glimpse on sites like lynda,because i search over the youtube and find one hour video not clear the speaking fast  ?

Comment: Well Anthony van der Hoorn (http://stackoverflow.com/users/252895/anthonyv) has some small video's on [his Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/anthonyvdh), one of them introducing the Glimpse Webforms plugin. Anthony also did a [great talk about Glimpse at NDC Oslo in 2013](https://vimeo.com/68383351) which gives you even more details about the what and why of Glimpse